# .xsl file does not download by browser from tomcat7

Tags: java, tomcat, xslt

am getting issue when try to download .xsl file from website url
please suggest me solution

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ootFf.png)

Comment: That means the file does not exist at all or is in another location path

Comment: added path in docbase path in server.xml and file is exits

Comment: Then please provide more info as it is impossible to know what is wrong with just that. Also, please refer to [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It's an xls you're searching, not an xsl

Answer (score 2):

As status code specifies , the file does not exist. Make sure the file is in the proper location. You need to put it in the classpath or provide the full location of the file